# view Files on "Ready to Install" wizard page

Tags: inno-setup

I use a file for the [Files] section:

```
#define FileLine
#define FileIndex
#define FileCount
#define FileHandle
#dim FileList[65536]

    #sub ProcessFileLine
      #if FileLine != ""
        #expr FileList[FileCount] = FileLine
        #expr FileCount = ++FileCount
      #endif  
    #endsub
    #for {FileHandle = FileOpen(AppFiles); \
      FileHandle && !FileEof(FileHandle); \
      FileLine = FileRead(FileHandle)} \
      ProcessFileLine
    #if FileHandle
      #expr FileClose(FileHandle)
    #endif

    ...

   [Files]
#sub AddFileItem
  #emit 'Source: "' + FileList[FileIndex] + '"; DestDir: "{app}"'
#endsub
#for {FileIndex = 0; FileIndex < FileCount; FileIndex++} AddFileItem
```

How can I get the file names on the "Ready to Install" wizard page in a list?

Comment: That code looks like it's enumerating a single folder (`AppFiles`) and including a `[Files]` entry for eahc it finds. Why not use a wildcard? Also, what have you tried to do to set the ready memo? Can you show us your attempt at the `UpdateReadyMemo()` event function?

Comment: @Deanna, it seems to be part of [`this post`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11736521/960757), where I've used external file containing list of files whose are then added to the `[Files]` section at preprocessing time. In that post I've also shown how to list those files into a list box, which is close enough to finish what is needed here by yourself.