# List files in [Files] Section

Tags: inno-setup

I need to check the version of each file I have in my [Files] section of inno setup. For this, I need to get the list of these files.

Is this possible?

Is there an easier way to verify this information before starting the installation?

Comment: You don't need to care about this unless you use ignoreversion flag in your file entries. Inno Setup will overwrite files only when they have newer version info version number.

Comment: @TLama The reason for this is that if I locate any file with the same version of my Installer, I need to generate a log.

Comment: Well, [`here is`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11736521/960757) the only way to access the file list that I know at this time. Actually, your question is a duplicate of that one.

Comment: Thanks @TLama. I will see this.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want to do with it.

You can generate a list of files that have been included in the installer at compile time, by using the [`OutputManifestFile`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_outputmanifestfile.htm) directive, like so:

```
[Setup]
OutputManifestFile=contents.txt
```

This will include the filenames and other information of all files actually included.  However I believe it only includes the version information when you have **not** specified the `ignoreversion` flag (and normally you *should* specify this flag on application files).

This is mostly just something you can use for scripting or book-keeping in your development/build environment, however.  It's not really intended to affect the user experience in any way.

Typically if you want to verify the version of your installed application at runtime, you just pick one representative file (usually the main EXE for your application) and then use [code similar to this](http://vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Checking_current_application_version) to verify the version and act accordingly.