# How retrieve in [CODE] files loaded in [FILES]?

Tags: inno-setup

In [Files] I added

```
  Source: "files\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs;
```

now in [Code] I would like retrieve all folders with depth = 1.  For example:

```
files\some    
files\some2
```

Is it possible?

**edit:**
I found a solution using the preposessing:

```
#define FindHandle
#define FindResult
#define Mask ".\files\*.*"

#sub ProcessFoundFile
  #define FileName FindGetFileName(FindHandle)
  #if FileName == ".." || FileName == "."

  #else
  Log(' {#FileName}');
  #endif
#endsub

#for {FindHandle = FindResult = FindFirst(Mask, faDirectory); FindResult; FindResult = FindNext(FindHandle)} ProcessFoundFile
#if FindHandle
#expr FindClose(FindHandle)
#endif
```

Comment: Where do you want to *retrieve* them ? Note that these are source folders (known just at the compilation time) and you are asking how to get them in `[Code]` section which is a runtime section.

Comment: in an array,so since this i could know what files are included in the installer right?

Comment: You cannot [`access file list`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8924137/960757) from the `[Code]` section (if that is your aim). But in your case it would be e.g. possible to let the preprocessor generate a text file with the file (and/or directory) list. Such text file you could then include in the setup and read it at runtime.

Comment: and i must manually write paths to that files? or exist a way to do it parsing the directory?

Comment: Preprocessor can list them for you. But it can either inline them in the script, or make a file with their list.