# Inno Setup Iterate over [Files] section in Pascal code

Tags: loops, inno-setup, pascalscript

In an Inno Setup script, I need to copy a number of files to multiple user-defined locations. In order to do this, I'd like to iterate over the sources in the `[Files]` section, and `FileCopy()` them multiple times depending on the user-defined settings and properties of the files.

Is it possible to access the sources in the `[Files]` section using a script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot iterate the `[Files]` section.

---

But you can use preprocessor to generate both the `[Files]` section and the Pascal Script from one list of files.

You are not very specific about your goals, so I'm showing only a rough concept.

```
; Define array of files to work with
#dim Files[2]
#define Files[0] "MyProg.exe"
#define Files[1] "MyProg.chm"

#define I

; Iterate the file array, generating one entry in Run section for each file    
[Files]
#sub FileEntry
Source: "{#Files[I]}"; DestDir: "{app}"
#endsub

#for {I = 0; I < DimOf(Files); I++} FileEntry


[Code]

procedure CopyFiles;
begin
  // Iterate the file array, generating two FileCopy calls for each file    
#sub FileCopy
  FileCopy('{#Files[I]}', 'd:\destination1\{#Files[I]}', True);
  FileCopy('{#Files[I]}', 'd:\destination2\{#Files[I]}', True);
#endsub

#for {I = 0; I < DimOf(Files); I++} FileCopy
end;

// Just for debugging purposes, outputs the preprocessed script
// so you can verify if the code generation went right
#expr SaveToFile(AddBackslash(SourcePath) + "Preprocessed.iss")
```

If you compile the script, you can see in the preprocessed file `Preprocessed.iss` that it generates this:

```
[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "MyProg.chm"; DestDir: "{app}"

[Code]
procedure CopyFiles;
begin
  FileCopy('MyProg.exe', 'd:\destination1\MyProg.exe', True);
  FileCopy('MyProg.exe', 'd:\destination2\MyProg.exe', True);
  FileCopy('MyProg.chm', 'd:\destination1\MyProg.chm', True);
  FileCopy('MyProg.chm', 'd:\destination2\MyProg.chm', True);
end;
```

---

Actually you may not need to use the `FileCopy` for this specific purpose. You can just have the preprocessor generate multiple `[Files]` section entries for the same file:

```
; Iterate the file array, generating one entry in Run section for each file    
[Files]
#sub FileEntry
Source: "{#Files[I]}"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "{#Files[I]}"; DestDir: "d:\destination1"
Source: "{#Files[I]}"; DestDir: "d:\destination2"
#endsub
```

Generates:

```
[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "d:\destination1"
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "d:\destination2"
Source: "MyProg.chm"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "MyProg.chm"; DestDir: "d:\destination1"
Source: "MyProg.chm"; DestDir: "d:\destination2"
```

Inno Setup will identify identical source files and will pack them only once.

You can use [`Check` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck) to make some entries conditional.

---

See also this question, which is actually similar:
[Access file list via script in InnoSetup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8924137/850848)